# Is EcmaScript grammar left factored

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction

If I want to use a predictive parser the following grammar is not suitable:

```
E -> T + E | T
```

As I understand the problem with this grammar is that the non-terminal `T` is specified in multiple productions. So if a parser looks ahead the next token `T` it doesn't know which production to use because `T` is mentioned in several productions.

So the grammar has to be refactored to

```
E -> T X
X -> +E | e
```

Now, if I look at the [EcmaScript grammar](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-expressions) most non-terminal symbols have multiple productions with the same non-terminal. For example, `PropertyDefinition` symbol is repeated in both productions:

```
PropertyDefinitionList[Yield, Await]:
    PropertyDefinition[?Yield, ?Await]
    PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield, ?Await], PropertyDefinition[?Yield, ?Await]
```

So is my understanding correct that the EcmaScript grammar is not left-factored and if I want to use with a predictive top-down parser it has to be refactored?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thanks. Just to clarify, without left-factoring it I can use backtracking, right?

Comment: You can, but it might be inefficient.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, yeah, thanks for your input