# How can `AssignmentExpression` be derived from `Statement` in EcmaScript grammar

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, context-free-grammar, compiler-construction

Suppose I have the following part of JS code:

```
const v = 3;
```

As I understand it can be parsed as [AssignmentExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-AssignmentExpression):

```
AssignmentExpression :
    LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
```

Now I'm wondering how it can be derived from the [Statement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-StatementList)? One possible route is:

```
Statement -> ExpressionStatement -> Expression -> AssignmentExpression
```

But I'm not sure about that. Is it correct?

Here is how I found it:

`AssignmentExpression` is part [Expression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-Expression):

```
Expression :
    AssignmentExpression
    Expression, AssignmentExpression
```

then `Expression` is part of [ExpressionStatement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-ExpressionStatement) is

```
ExpressionStatement:

    [lookahead ∉ { {, function, ..., let [ }] Expression;
```

and then `ExpressionStatement` is part of [Statement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-Statement):

```
Statement :
    ExpressionStatement
```

Comment: First: `const v = 3;` is **not** an assignment expression.  It's a `const` declaration. The initialization part *looks* like an assignment expression, but it's a separate part of the grammar.

Comment: JavaScript grammar relies pretty heavily on keywords and tokens at the beginning of grammar constructs, and declarations are a good example of that. If the first token in the statement is `const` or `let` or `var`, then it's a declaration, not an expression statement.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for pointing that out. Const declaration you're talking about seems to be part of `LexicalDeclaration: LetOrConst BindingList`. If I now follow the grammar it's these derivations that I should use: `StatementListItem -> Declaration -> LexicalDeclaration`. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Pointy, and `AssignmentExpression` based on the grammar seems to be these cases `o.a = 3`, `()=>{}`. Correct?

Comment: Right. The answer below was given by somebody much less lazy than me :)

Comment: @Pointy, okay, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const v = 3;` is a declaration, not an assignment. Interestingly declarations aren't `Statement`s, but can appear in `StatementList`s. So you can't derive `const v = 3;` from `Statement`, but you can derive it from `StatementList`. So if you have a script containing only `const v = 3;`, the full derivation would be:

```
            Script
               |
          ScriptBody
               |
         StatementList
               |
       StatementListItem
               |
          Declaration
               |
      LexicalDeclaration
     /         |        \
LetOrConst BindingList  ';'
    |           |
 'const'   LexicalBinding
             /          \
     BindingIdentifier  Initializer
            |                |
         Identifier    AssignmentExpression
            |                  |
       IdentifierName         ...
            |                  |
           'v'                '5'
```

An actual assignment would be just `v = 5;`. That would go through `ExpressionStatement` and the derivation from `Statement` would look like this:

```
                     Statement
                         |
               ExpressionStatement
                     /        \
                   Expression ';'
                        |
              AssignmentExpression
             /          |         \
LeftHandSideExpression '=' AssignmentExpression
         |                         |
    NewExpression                ...
         |                         |
   MemberExpression               '5'
         |
   PrimaryExpression              
         |
IdentifierReference
         |
     Identifier
         |
   IdentifierName
         |
        'v'
```

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding `MemberExpression` that was missing in you diagram. This diagram is such a great help. I'm wondering what are these tree dots `...`?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com The three dots are just me not wanting to list all the derivations from `AssignmentExpression` to '5' ;-)

Comment: @sepp2k, I see :). But now I'm trying to see how I can get to `5` from `AssignmentExpression` and don't find a way. Can you take a look please?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com You always go down the production that just goes to the next-lower rule until you arrive at PrimaryExpression.

Comment: @sepp2k, that's what I did. None of the productions of the `AssignmentExpression` seem to lead to the `NumericLiteral`.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Assignment -> Conditional -> LogicalOr -> LogicalAnd -> Bitwise(Or -> Xor -> And) -> Equality -> Relational -> Shift -> Add -> Mult -> Exponential -> Unary -> Update -> LHS -> New -> Member -> Primary -> Literal -> Numeric.

Comment: @sepp2k, thanks! that's so long, indirect and I'd say unexpected 
path.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com That's why I just wrote "..." ;-) The basic idea is that the rules are order by precedence starting with the lowest precedence. Then each rule uses the one with the next-higher precedence as its base case. So, say, an additive expression is a multiplicative expression followed by zero or more additive operators+operands. So if you want to get to the lowest precedence rule (i.e. primary expression), you'll have to go through all the other operators in between.

Comment: @sepp2k, thanks for the hint! Indeed, just checked this [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and the order is similar to the productions if one goes upwards from the `Assignment`. Will practice parsing complex assignment expression to understand the idea better. Good luck! :)

Comment: @sepp2k, I'm back with new questions :). Can you please take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46048160/2545680)? And do you know if EcmaScript uses some arbitrary notation for the grammar (single semicolon, multiple semicolon, alternations specified in the new row instead of using or `|` symbol) or it's some kind of existing standard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156744/discussion-between-sepp2k-and-angularindepth-com).